# Autoresize UITableViewCell while UITableView uses autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nib, autoresizingmask

I have a nib for a `UITableViewCell` which uses autoresizing.

I have a nib for a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` subview which uses autolayout. This `UITableView` uses cells using the described `UITableViewCell` nib.

I would prefer to remain using autoresizing with the UITableViewCell, however, the autoresizing masks of the `UITableViewCell` subviews are not being respected. Additionally, setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` in the `initWithCoder:` method of the `UITableViewCell` changes nothing.

How can I get the `UITableViewCell` to layout using the autoresizing mask?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't switched on constraints (`Use Autolayout` is ticked) for any of the Xibs?

Comment: The `UIViewController` nib has Autolayout ticked. The `UITableViewCell` nib does not have Autolayout ticked.

Comment: Fixed the description, sorry :\